# IBM WAS 8.0 to 8.5.5 migration

Tags: migration, websphere

I am asked to upgrade IBM WebSphere application server 8.0 to 8.5.5 on linux environment. Could you please give me a step by step guide for this migration?

thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Sure, my hourly rate is 80 Dollar.

Comment: Start with this [How do I migrate, coexist, and interoperate?](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc/ae/welc_howdoi_tmig.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-4-0-1&lang=en)

Comment: Thanks Gas. Let me check this article.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method (assuming your WebSphere instances have enough spare CPU/disk/etc) is to build a second WebSphere cell at the new level and migrate applications across one at a time.   Access to the application servers should be controlled by either a web server (using the WAS plugin) or an IP sprayer product and which version of app server used should be controlled in that layer.   Updating in place has many pitfalls and can be difficult to recover from if something goes wrong which can lead to extended down time for your applications.